# Second page opened via ajax not triggering javascript

Tags: javascript

This is more of a design question.

I have some jQuery code that inside `$(document).ready()` on a .js file called from page `A.html` and page `B.html` and works ok.

On page `A.html` there's a link to open `B.html` via ajax using a bootstrap modal.

Page `B.html` opens on page `A.html` as modal as expected, **however all the javascript of `B.html` is not being rendered even if its already there.**

So, my current workaround to make it work, which doesn't feel very natural to me is putting all code into functions like this.

```
$.fn.myFunction = function() {
  // my code here
};
```

And then detecting the ajax, doing eval and call the method again

```
$(".btn-that-opens-modal").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
  eval(xhr.responseText);
  $("body").MyFunction();
});
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery AJAX calls will execute JavaScript when it's inserted in the DOM, as long as [cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) requirements are met.

For example, if the following are *both on the same server* and *not using `file://` protocol*, this will work fine:

A.html:

```
<sript src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#my-modal').load('B.html');
    });
</script>
<div id="my-modal"></div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

B.html:

```
<h1>B Modal</h1>
<script>
    // note that it's not necessary to wrap this in a $(document).ready
    // function; since this is designed to be loaded by jQuery AJAX from
    // a $(document).ready function, we can assume the document is ready.
    // however, it won't hurt or cause any issues to use a $(document).ready
    // function here
    $('#test').html('I come from B...');
</script>
```

So note the two important caveats:

**Both `A.html` and `B.html` are on the same server** (or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is set properly):

If `A.html` tries to load `B.html` via AJAX from a different server, the request is subject to CORS.  Unless the appropriate header (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) is configured on the server providing `B.html`, the browser will refuse to load it (including JavaScript execution).

**You can't use the `file://` protocol**:

If you're just creating `.html` files and then loading them in a browser (by double-clicking or the like), you're loading them up implicitly with the `file://` protocol.  At least on Chrome, you're not allowed to load AJAX scripts with the `file://` protocol.  So you have to actually set up a server to make this function work.

I tested this code with the following Node/Express app:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/a(.html)?', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('A.html');
});

app.get('/b(.html)?', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('B.html');
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on 3000');
});
```

And it worked as expected.

Answer (score -1):

The javascript won't run for security reasons if you are getting it from somewhere other than your domain, this is due to the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). If you were getting a page from some third party with ajax they could embed malicious javascript and if your browser immediately executed it you would have some problems.... If you need to retrieve script from somewhere other than your domain please use Ethan Browns answer. However if the html with embedded javascript is being retrieved from within your domain then the javascript should run. For example, if I have an `index.html` and a `modal.html`.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fetch-modal">modal popup</div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('#fetch-modal').click(function(e) 
      $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'modal.html',
        success: function(html) {
          $('body').append(html);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

modal.html

```
<script>
   console.log('hey');
</script>
```

when clicking the div#link the embedded script will be appended to the body of the index.html and the console will log out 'hey'. I hope that this further clarifies what I was trying to say with my pre-edit answer. My apologies for being unclear and wrong.

Comment: Ok, but if the javascript is on page A, why isn't immediately available on page B when is loaded via modal? Even if using eval as my example above I need to manually reload the functions to make it work.

Comment: Wilfred, this answer isn't correct.  Particularly, the statement "The javascript won't run for security reasons."  jQuery *will* indeed run JavaScript loaded via AJAX when it's loaded in the DOM *provided that* CORS restrictions are observed.  See my answer for more info.

Comment: @Martin I think you're running into an issue where the javascript on page A has already run on $(document).ready so when you load in B.html after $(document).ready is fired the javascript on A needs to be run again for it to apply to B.

Comment: @EthanBrown, I made some edits to my answer, I was dreadfully unclear and inaccurate before, thank you for pointing that out. For my own learning, is this answer correct?

Comment: Yep, much better.  I might say that you're making an *assumption* (probably correct) that the OP's problem is due to security/CORS issues...it could be something else entirely.  But it's a pretty safe assumption.